# Powershell : Open closed site exception

Tags: 2013, powershell

I am trying to open closed site using the following code

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -erroraction SilentlyContinue

$URL="http://1111:39993/sites/test17081"
$spWeb = Get-SPWeb $URL

$isClosed = [Microsoft.Office.RecordsManagement.InformationPolicy.ProjectPolicy]::IsProjectClosed($spWeb)

If ($isClosed)
{
    write-host  "site is closed :" , $spWeb.url
    [Microsoft.Office.RecordsManagement.InformationPolicy.ProjectPolicy]::OpenProject($spWeb)

    $spWeb.Update()
}
```

it raised the following exception :
(**Exception calling "OpenProject" with "1" argument(s): "Sorry, this site hasn't been shared with you."**)

However when I do the same but close project instead of open it, it working fine.
BTY I am site collection administrator

Please advice !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My college proposed solution for me and it working well that use elevated privilegses :

```
[Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity]::RunWithElevatedPrivileges(
    {

        #write code here 
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

May be there is right issue for the user running PowerShell script, Check the Permissions and try again.

Comment: The user who run PowerShell is site collection admin so what right permission needed ?

Comment: and if there is missing permission , why CloseProject() works fine with the same user ?